# Silverlight 4.0 lacks C# 4.0 language support?

Tags: silverlight-4.0, c#-4.0

The below code compiles with .Net Framework 4.0 but not with Silverlight 4.0.
I would appreciate if anyone could shed some light on this.   Here're the error messages I'm getting:

```
Error   1   The best overloaded method match for 'ThinkFarAhead.Confounded.Client.Models.Consumer.SetFunctionalAreas(System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable<ThinkFarAhead.Confounded.Client.Models.IFunctionalArea>)' has some invalid arguments    c:\Hanu\SilverlightApplication1\Test.cs 64  13  SilverlightApplication1
Error   3   The best overloaded method match for 'ThinkFarAhead.Confounded.Client.Models.Consumer.SetFunctionalAreas(System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable<ThinkFarAhead.Confounded.Client.Models.IFunctionalArea>)' has some invalid arguments    c:\Hanu\SilverlightApplication1\Test.cs 65  13  SilverlightApplication1
Error   2   Argument 1: cannot convert from 'ThinkFarAhead.Confounded.Web.EntitySet<ThinkFarAhead.Confounded.Web.FunctionalArea>' to 'System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable<ThinkFarAhead.Confounded.Client.Models.IFunctionalArea>'   c:\Hanu\SilverlightApplication1\Test.cs 64  47  SilverlightApplication1
Error   4   Argument 1: cannot convert from 'ThinkFarAhead.Confounded.Web.EntitySet<ThinkFarAhead.Confounded.Web.FunctionalArea>' to 'System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable<ThinkFarAhead.Confounded.Client.Models.IFunctionalArea>'   c:\Hanu\SilverlightApplication1\Test.cs 65  47  SilverlightApplication1
```

What I'm trying to do:
Extend generated entities (RIA) on Silverlight (4.0) side to make multiple entities with common features share the same interface (A control needs to use multiple objects the same way.  These objects are pretty much the same).

Thanks in advance.

```
using System;
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using ThinkFarAhead.Confounded.Client.Models;
using ThinkFarAhead.Confounded.Web;


namespace ThinkFarAhead.Confounded.Web
{

    public class Entity { }

    public class EntitySet<T> : IEnumerable<T>, IEnumerable where T : Entity
    {
        List<T> list = new List<T>();
        public IEnumerator<T> GetEnumerator()
        {
            return (IEnumerator<T>)list;
        }

        IEnumerator IEnumerable.GetEnumerator()
        {
            return GetEnumerator();
        }

        public void Add(T newone)
        {
            list.Add(newone);
        }
    }

    public partial class FunctionalArea : Entity
    {
        public string Name { get; set; }
    }

    public partial class FunctionalArea : IFunctionalArea { }

}

namespace ThinkFarAhead.Confounded.Client.Models
{


    public interface IFunctionalArea
    {
        string Name { get; set; }
    }


    public class Variance
    {
        public static EntitySet<FunctionalArea> FunctionalAreas
        {
            get
            {
                return new EntitySet<FunctionalArea>();
            }
        }

        public static void Main()
        {
            var abc = new EntitySet<FunctionalArea>();
            new Consumer().SetFunctionalAreas(abc);
            new Consumer().SetFunctionalAreas(FunctionalAreas);
        }
    }

    public class Consumer
    {

        public void SetFunctionalAreas(IEnumerable<IFunctionalArea> areas)
        {
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Maybe you could post the errors you get?

Comment: In addition to Ken's comment -- consider posting a *minimal* failing case. This will allow a more focused question.

Comment: Feel free to post a question.

Comment: I think it may have to do with http://forums.silverlight.net/forums/p/184882/421878.aspx

Comment: @Ken, Gabe:  Apologies.  Edited to include errors.

Comment: @pst:  Unfortunately this is the minimum I wrote to reproduce the issue exactly as per my implementation (wanted to get everything of consequence to the error in)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As Austin said in SL4 you can't just pass your collection with type `IEnumerable<FunctionalArea>` as parameter when your method expects a `IEnumerable<IFunctionalArea>`.

But if you don't want to go 'dynamic', don't forget you can still do this (using System.Linq) :

```
var abc = new EntitySet<FunctionalArea>();
new Consumer().SetFunctionalAreas(abc.Cast<IFunctionalArea>());
new Consumer().SetFunctionalAreas(FunctionalAreas.Cast<IFunctionalArea>());
```

Not quite elegant, but hey, that does the trick ;)

Answer (score 1):

The BCLs in Silverlight don't have covariant/contravariant markers (`IEnumerable<T>` is not marked as `IEnumerable<out T>` as in .NET Framework, for example).

User code can use these features, it's just framework code that doesn't - a limitation of the platform today.

Comment: Hi Austin, Nice to meet you again :)  And are there plans to fix the framework in SL 5.0?

Comment: I can't comment on Silverlight 5 features except what has been discussed at the Silverlight Firestarter, which was more high-level features (such as 64-bit, hardware decoded video, etc.).

Comment: Well, an elegant solution gone a-wasted ;)  I figure I need to go 'dynamic' all the way on this one.  (Return 'dynamic' and use it only in XAML.  If needed in ViewModel, grit your teeth and typecast).  Posting so could help someone.  Thanks for your answer.

Comment: Just curious:  Was there a technical reason for not the SL 4.0 BCLs not carrying the markers?

Comment: @Vyas: None that anybody outside Microsoft should have to know about.  Our internal processes for building the framework have some...quirks, let's say, that make this harder than one might think.